# How can I disable logging from certain classes when using a common logger?

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, configure, java.util.logging

I have created a common logger in the following manner in a root class that is referenced by many sub classes.

```
public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(RootClass.class.getName());
```

Then  I am accessing that logger in child classes in the following manner.

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = RootClass.LOGGER;
```

I have a main classes which receives inputs from users and it calls a method in the RootClass to configure the logger.

```
logStatus = messageBus.configureLogPath(logPath,logLevel);
```

Below is the implementation of the above method.

```
public Boolean configureLogPath(String logPath,String level) {
    Boolean result=false;
    switch(level) {
        case "info" :
            LOGGER.setLevel(Level.INFO);
            break;
        case "severe":
            LOGGER.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
            break;
        case "debug":
            LOGGER.setLevel(Level.CONFIG);
            break;
        case "off" :
            LOGGER.setLevel(Level.OFF);
            break;
        default : 
            LOGGER.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
    }
     try {
        simpleFormatter = new SimpleFormatter();
        logFileHandler = new FileHandler(logPath);
        logFileHandler.setFormatter(simpleFormatter);


        LOGGER.addHandler(logFileHandler);
        result =true;
    } catch (SecurityException e1) {
        result= false;
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Security exception when reading log file" + e1);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        result = false;
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "IO Exception when reading log file" + e1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is it possible for me to disable logging from certain selected child classes? I have a requirement where the user should be able to set certain child classes for which the logs should be created. But since I am using a common logger in all the child classes I am not sure how to achieve this. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To meet your requirements you have to create a custom [log filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Filter.html) that checks the [source class name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogRecord.html#getSourceClassName()) and install it on the root logger.

```
public class SourceFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord record) {
        //Source class can return null so handle it.
        String cn = String.valueOf(record.getSourceClassName());
        return !cn.startsWith("foo.bar.Child1")
                && !cn.startsWith("foo.bar.Child2")
                && !cn.startsWith("foo.bar.Child3");
    }
}
```

Also, the level class has a [parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html#parse(java.lang.String)) method you can use to get rid of that switch statement.

Answer (score 1):

We can mention the below code for logging off from particular Java Classes as:

```
Logger.getLogger("cs.fid.tm.reportingService.config.test1").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Comment: I cannot use this to turnoff logs from a child class because those child classes are using the logger from the root class. Are there any ways to do this when I am using a common logger through out these classes? I had to use a common logger because I need to the outputs of all classes to go into a single log file.

Comment: Note that you have to keep this Logger reference from being GC'd, or it will be undone.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you could always just walk the call stack and see where your function was called from. Perhaps not the most efficient solution, but it should work in your case.

Comment: I need a way to turn off logs from certain classes as thats the exact requirement :(