# How generate log files separated by apps running over websphere 9 ? I use java.util.logging to generate logs

Tags: java, ejb, websphere, java.util.logging

I use websphere 9 application server to deploy war's and ear's, and use java.util.logging to generate logs into applications. I try to use properties file to configure the FileHandler of the LogManager, but websphere write ALL other logs on my file. 
I not use log4j because i can't set log levels at runtime.

Is possible make differents file logs by application over websphere with java.util.logging ?

```
This is my properties file Logger.properties

handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler
#java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
#java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

# Set the default formatter to be the simple formatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter =java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
# Use UTF-8 encoding
java.util.logging.FileHandler.encoding  = UTF-8
# Write the log files to some file pattern
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = C:/Users/pmendez/Documents/Log/testLogs.log
# Limit log file size to 5 Kb
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 5000
# Keep 10 log files
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 10
#Customize the SimpleFormatter output format 
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format = %d [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

Comment: Please include your logging.properties in your question.

Comment: Ok, I include this. I'ts located on Shared Libraries of Websphere.

Answer (score 0):

> I try to use properties file to configure the FileHandler of the LogManager, but websphere write ALL other logs on my file.

Per your logging.properties you are attaching the FileHandler to the root logger.  It would be expected to see log records from WebSphere because by default [Logger::setUseParentHandlers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/Logger.html#setUseParentHandlers(boolean)) is set to true.

> Is possible make differents file logs by application over websphere with java.util.logging ?

You have to do one of the following:

1. Attach your FileHandler to the root logger of your application so the FileHandler is not attached to parent of the WebSphere application.  Say application package is `com.my.app.rules` you can add entry of to`com.my.app.rules.handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler` and remove the attachment to the root logger.  Next you demand the logger from code and pin it to memory so this package becomes the new root logger of your application code.
2. Create [java.util.logging.Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33538174/how-can-i-disable-logging-from-certain-classes-when-using-a-common-logger/33548085#33548085) and install it on the FileHandler.
3. Turn off the logging for WebSphere.  You can do this by setting the root logger to off  and forcing all of your loggers to say info.

   `.level=OFF
   com.my.app.rules.class1.level=INFO
   com.my.app.rules.class2.level=INFO
   com.my.app.rules.class3.level=INFO`

> It's possible set one FileHandler by app ?

The default [java.util.logging.LogManager](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) only supports one set of FileHandler settings.  You can attach instances to various loggers but it doesn't allow for instances with different settings via the logging.properties.  However, the LogManager does support per the documentation:

> A property "config". This property is intended to allow arbitrary configuration code to be run. The property defines a whitespace or comma separated list of class names. A new instance will be created for each named class. The default constructor of each class may execute arbitrary code to update the logging configuration, such as setting logger levels, adding handlers, adding filters, etc.

So what you need to do is bundle a configuration class with your application that performs the needed FileHandler and logger configuration and modify your logging.properties to load it.  One issue with this approach is that the LogManager can only see classes from the system class loader.

Comment: Applications are on a Cluster implemented over Websphere 9, We implement a particular Logger Interface wich is used by each application to write Logs. We need one log file by application. I try your solution, but I can't reference classes statistically. It's possible set one FileHandler by app ? We use on our Logger some code like: InputStream configFile = LoggerJUL.class.getResourceAsStream("/Logger.properties"); LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(configFile);

Comment: @PabloMendez Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From jmehrens answer you can see it might be a bit difficult. Maybe you should consider switching logging to [High Performance Extensible Logging (HPEL)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/ctrb_HPELOverview.html). It is just setting in the application server, so no changes in the applications code.

Then you could query logs for the given application using [command line tool](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rtrb_logviewer.html):

```
logViewer.sh -includeExtensions appName=PlantsByWebSphere
```

This would be much easier, if it fits your purpose. Moreover, generating separate log files is now not recommended, if you plan to move your apps in the future into containers/cloud or refactor them into microservices.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this isue was create a PersonalFileHandler to use on all Logger's. Properties are read from properties file called "Logger.properties", and invoque read this programmatically, same like this:

```
//Read config file
LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(LoggerJUL.class.getResourceAsStream("/Logger.properties"));
//Add handler to logger
Logger.getLogger(clazz)).addHandler(new PersonalFileHandler());
```

PersonalFileHandler extends FileHandler, and properties are set by configure method on FileHandler class on runtime.

Comment: Open a new question using the last paragraph of this answer.  Remove the last paragraph from this answer.

Comment: Ok. Thank's. I create another question.